# Sql "IN" is slower then simple `field_name`="some". Why?

Tags: mysql, database

Why my MySQL query

```
SELECT ... WHERE `field_name`="some";
```

is processed faster then

```
SELECT ... WHERE `field_name` IN( "some" );
```

'IN' uses binary search, while the simple `field_name`="some" uses the simple line-by-line searching. I am right, amn't I?

PS: it was tested in the table with < 100 lines. Maybe IN spends more time to "takeoff", but in big tables works faster?

Associated quastion, - does binary search applies either to IN values, or to lines in the table, or maby to both?

Comment: Is `field_name` indexed?

Comment: @RiggsFolly

yes it is `unique` (if I understand you right)

Comment: Then it is using the index on the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly, where i can read about this, could you give me a link? Are indexed fields incerease the simple queries speed, or reduce "in" one?

Comment: You would be very likely to fond this sort of information in the MYSQL Manual.

Comment: Can you please provide the explain plans for both? Sounds to me that if you have only one constant value in the IN clause, the optimizer should be converting it to the same plan as with the equals operator.

Answer (score 0):

The IN statement in MySQL presumes an array of possible values that will be compared against every single row on the table/result set. While the WHERE clause uses single value comparison, uses indexes (if available) and mysql is optimizing the query in most of the cases.